# On Android, How can I get a small .png to appear where I tapped with my finger with the camera active

Tags: android, image, camera, overlay

Thanks in advance for your time!

This has been bothering me for quite some time now. What I want is to display a small .png image on the screen where I tapped my finger, with the camera being active. I don't want any picture to be taken or anything, I only want it to display what the camera sees and on top of that, a small .png file.

I'm trying to make a geographic game where you are able to "shoot" your opponent in the end by seeing through the camera, and tapping him on the screen, to shoot him.

I'm kind of new at this, so the code I made is useless, for anybody, me included :S

Any help or advice is much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

To make this effect, first of all you can't use the default Camera App, like this:
`Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");`
because you can't modify anything on this activity.

And actuary you can write an activity use `hardware.camera` to take picture.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html
This will need some knowledge about `SurfaceView` to show the camera preview and the small .png images, but I'm sure you will find a lot of examples around the Internet.